# How to add a situational field to a Serializer?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to figure out the best way to handle a situation where a model may have sensitive information that I only want the `owner` to be able to see.

For example the store below:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Account, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    license= models.CharField(max_length=128)
    menu = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

class StoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = AccountSerializer(read_only=True)
    menu = ProductSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    address = AddressSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Store

        fields = ('owner', 'name', 'menu', 'address', 'license')
```

In this example I want all users to be able to find stores but the `license` field should only be available to CRUD if the user is the owner of this object.

What is the optimal solution in this case?
My options so far seem to be:

A) Create a separate serializer for the owner type

B) Turn license into a SerializerMethodField and provide it optionally from there

I'm wondering which is the better practice and if there are other more elegant ways of doing this.

Comment: better practice is option A IMO and it's what I've seen others do.  You can extend / modify in the future more easily and have better code organization.  It also logically belongs to the view layer to choose which serializer to use as this defines the view. DRF views natively provide for this kind of serializer switching.

Comment: You should have separate serializer and decide which serializer to use on view. Since view is where authorization takes place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way around, in my opinion, would be to create two different serializers, depending on the user that is going to perform the request. Rephrasing from DRF Docs:

> *get_serializer_class(self)*
>
> Returns the class that should be used for the serializer. Defaults to returning the serializer_class attribute.
>
> May be overridden to provide dynamic behavior, such as using different serializers for read and write operations, or **providing different serializers to different types of users.**

That will further allow you to check the condition of `Store` ownership inside an overrided `get_serializer_class` of a view that inherits from `GenericAPIView` class, and to choose between the usage of one or another serializer. Exemplifying this:

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):

    queryset = Store.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        # Here you will provide the implementation of the checking function
        if self.request.user.is_store_owner():
            return PrivateStoreSerializer
        return PublicStoreSerializer
```

Comment: Specific to the line 
    if self.request.user.is_store_owner():
How would I go about accessing the object being requested to compare against the logged in user?

Comment: @SaumilPatel Actually, the very same variable `self.request.user` here will give you the user that performed the request.